# Undefined method `image' in Shrine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, shrine

I try to add Shrine gem to an existing project that uses Paperclip. I added a Shrine image to a new model (just for a check). So I created model Country with this db table:

```
  create_table "countries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "image_data"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

and this model:

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  include ImageUploader::Attachment(:image)

  validates :name, length: { in: 2..180 }, presence: true
end
```

After that I tried to get image from country and received this (image_data works, though):

[image]

I thought that maybe it's because image is empty, but in another app with shrine everything works correctly

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you add image_uploader.rb file in lib folder?

Comment: @bravemaster I followed shrine setup guide and added image_uploader.rb in app/uploaders folder. File image_uploader.rb contains no uploading logic, but the previous time I did this in another app everything worked.

Comment: How about restarting your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that somehow shrine uploader was loaded before shrine.rb file so that I couldn't use any shrine methods. Similar issue can be found here: https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine/issues/155

Adding `require_relative '../../config/initializers/shrine'` to the uploader resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I got the error in shrine version 3.2.1 and fixed it by adding `Shrine.plugin :activerecord` in `shrine.rb`. hope it can help.

https://shrinerb.com/docs/plugins/activerecord